# I want to force change password on first login Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, boolean

I have a custom User model with field is_resetpwd as a boolean field with default value True
I want that to change to False when the password is changed, following is my password change view

class ChangePasswordView(APIView):

```
    """
    An endpoint for changing password.
    """
    serializer_class = ChangePasswordSerializer
    model = User
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = self.request.user
        # print("obj", obj)
        return obj

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            # Check old password

            if not self.object.check_password(serializer.data.get("old_password")):
                return Response({"old_password": ["Wrong password."]}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            # set_password also hashes the password that the user will get
            self.object.set_password(serializer.data.get("new_password"))
            self.object.save()


            response = {
                'message': 'Password updated successfully',
            }

            return Response(response)


        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

what should I add in this to change my boolean value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before save() add this

```
self.object.is_resetpwd = False
```

and then save the objects just like before

The updated code will look like this

```
"""
An endpoint for changing passwords.
"""
serializer_class = ChangePasswordSerializer
model = User
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj = self.request.user
    # print("obj", obj)
    return obj

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()

    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        # Check old password

        if not self.object.check_password(serializer.data.get("old_password")):
            return Response({"old_password": ["Wrong password."]}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        # set_password also hashes the password that the user will get
        self.object.set_password(serializer.data.get("new_password"))
        self.object.is_resetpwd = False
        self.object.save()


        response = {
            'message': 'Password updated successfully',
        }

        return Response(response)


    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```